# Python3 pip install gives “Command ”python setup.py egg_info“ failed with error code 1” in pydns package

Tags: python, package, pip, installation

I'm new to python and have been trying to install some packages with pip. I always get this error message though:

[image]

Right now i'm using python3 and virtual environment i.e. "everify"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably because you are using the incorrect package. I think you might need py3dns package since you are using Python 3.